# Why does one of these code segment work while the other throws an overflow

Tags: python, exponential

I am working with python and I am trying to find powers of really large numbers but something interesting which happens is that this throws a math overflow

```
math.pow(1000, 1000)
```

but this below seems to work although I do not know if the value returned is correct

```
1000**1000
```

Anybody aware why this happens

Comment: Because python is awesome ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[math.pow](http://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow):

> Unlike the built-in `**` operator, `math.pow()` converts both its arguments to type `float`. Use `**` or the built-in `pow()` function for computing exact integer powers.

Comment: any idea on the limits beyond which we cannot assume that the value returned is correct for any of these?

Comment: Also, because math.pow returns float result, and 1000^1000 will not fit not float anyhow

Comment: @cobie Integer math is always correct. Floating point math is correct up to rounding error, or until you hit the maximum value of `sys.float_info.max`.

Answer (score 8):

Simple, the `math.pow()` method uses C float libraries, while the `**` power operator uses integer maths.

The two methods have different limitations. Python `int` size is only limited by how much memory your OS will let Python have, float numbers are limited by your computer architecture, see [`sys.float_info.max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.float_info).